# Проблема с подсчетом суммы в C#

Tags: c#

**Задача:** Даны числовой ряд и некоторое число e>0. Найти сумму тех членов последовательности ряда, модуль которых больше или равен заданному e.

Дана последовательность вида **An=n!/(2n)!**

***Мой код:***

```
class Program
{
    public static double fact(double f)
    {
        double fa = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= f; i++)
        {
            fa *= i;
        }
        return fa;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter E = ");
        double e = System.Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double j = 1;
        double n = fact(j) / fact(2*j);
        double sum = 0;

        while(Math.Abs(n) >= e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            sum += n;
            j++;
            n = fact(j) / fact(2*j);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("SUM= {0}", sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


}
```

**Возникает проблема при подсчете, когда начинаем рассматривать элемент порядком 5 и более.**

Например:

A5 = fact(5)/fact(5*2); // C# выводит нам 3,30687830687831E-05

Считаем это значение вручную. Получаем => fact(5)= 120; fact(10) = 3628800;

**120/3628800 = 0.00003306878**

**Вопрос:** Почему C# не вычисляет это именно так? Из-за этого код игнорирует данные значения и по условию они не проходят в сумму.

Comment: `3,30687830687831E-05` эквивалентно `3,30687830687831 * 10^-5` или `0,0000330687830687831`

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вашу функцию можно переписать:

```
public static int fact(int f)
    {
        int fa = 1;
        for (int i = f + 1; i <= f*2; i++)
        {
            fa *= i;
        }
        return fa;
    }
```

Таким образом вы будете вычислять только знаменатель, уже сокращенный с числителем.
Это будет работать быстрее чем отдельно вычислять числитель и знаменатель.
Теперь чтобы вычислить член вашей последовательности:
`double n = 1.0 / fact(i);`

***Возвращает `int` потому что факториал всегда целый**

---

Теперь, то что он отображает `3,30687830687831E-05` вместо `0.00003306878`, то это дефолтный вывод для `double`, который выводит с число с высокой точностью, чтобы изменить вывод(если уж он вас смущает) попробуйте поменять количество выводимых цифр после запятой:
`Console.WriteLine("{0:0.000000000}", n);`
Такой вывод даст 9 цифр после запятой.
* **Все вычисления правильные**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double e = 0.00000001;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0;;i++){
            double n = 1.0 / fact(i);
            if(n >= e){
                sum += n;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
```

Все работает верно.
При `E = 0.00000001` подходит 8 членов
При `E = 0.000000001` подходит 11 членов
И т.д.

А от модуля смысла нет, так как у вас число всегда положительное.